# How to get rid of stepping into stl_vector.h using gdb "s" command?

Tags: c++, gdb, stdvector

Subject.

Compiled: g++ -g -Wall -o program program.cpp

Running: gdb -tui program

Thank you,

Javier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have GDB 7.4 or greater, there's a `skip` command, which lets you skip functions or entire files. After you mark a file or function for skipping, it won't step into it again. From the GDB Manual -- [Skipping Over Functions and Files](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Skipping-Over-Functions-and-Files.html#Skipping-Over-Functions-and-Files)

```
skip [linespec]

skip function [linespec]
After running this command, the function named by linespec or the function containing the line named by linespec will be skipped over when stepping. 

skip file [filename]
After running this command, any function whose source lives in filename will be skipped over when stepping.
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `fin(ish)` command to step out of a function call. Or step over function calls using `n(ext)` command. See [Continuing and Stepping](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Continuing-and-Stepping.html#Continuing-and-Stepping).